# No me funciona el promedio dentro del for

Tags: java, bucle-for

Estoy haciendo un programa, tengo problema con el promedio que me da 0 , ya intente ponerlo afuera del `for` y pasa lo mismo , ¿alguien podria decirme mi error?

***Enunciado :***

*Dados los sueldos y categoria de 5 empleados se pide obtener.*

*a) Cantidad de sueldos <10000 en la categoria 1.*

*b) Cantidad de sueldos >= 12000 en la categoria2 y sueldos <=15000 en la categoria 3.*

*c) Cantidad de sueldos >15000.*

*d) Promedio de los sueldos de cada categoria.*

```
int categoria;
int categoria1 = 0;
int categoria2 = 0;
int categoria3 = 0;
int empleado = 6;
int sueldo = 0;
int promedio1 = 0;
int sumatoria1 = 0;
int sueldoTotal = 0;
int sumatoria2 = 0;
int sumatoria3 = 0;
int promedio2 = 0;
int promedio3 = 0;
Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);

for (int i = 1; i < empleado; i++) {

    System.out.println("Ingrese el numero de categoria : ");
    categoria = teclado.nextInt();
    System.out.println(i + "Ingrese sueldo : ");
    sueldo = teclado.nextInt();

    if (categoria == 1) {

        if (sueldo < 10000) {
            categoria1++;
        }

    }

    if (categoria == 2) {

        if (sueldo >= 12000) {

            categoria2++;
        }

    }

    if (categoria == 3) {
        if (sueldo <= 15000) {
            categoria3++;
        }

    }

    if (sueldo > 15000) {

        sueldoTotal++;
    }

    sumatoria1 += categoria1;
    sumatoria2 += categoria2;
    sumatoria3 += categoria3;

    promedio1 = sumatoria1 / 5;
    promedio2 = sumatoria2 / 5;
    promedio3 = sumatoria3 / 5;

}

System.out.println("a)Cantidad de sueldos < 10000 en la categoria 1 : " + categoria1);
System.out.println("b1)Cantidad de sueldos >= 12000 en la categoria 2 : " + categoria2);
System.out.println("b2)Cantidad de sueldos <= 15000 en la categoria 3 : " + categoria3);
System.out.println("c)Cantidad de sueldos > 15000 : " + sueldoTotal);
System.out.println("El promedio de la categoria 1 : " + promedio1);
System.out.println("El promedio de la categoria 2 : " + promedio2);
System.out.println("El promedio de la categoria 3 : " + promedio3);
```

Comment: java @JackNavaRow

Comment: y por cierto que error te da?

Comment: El promedio lo tienes que calcular en con un tipo de dato que acepte números racionales, por ejemplo float o double, ya que en int siempre te arrojará el numero entero, en este caso, 0. Saludos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Me parece que el único problema es en los promedios, primeramente debes tomar en cuenta que el promedio debe ser:

```
 suma de sueldos de categoría / número de registros en categoría
```

así que no debes definir un valor fijo de 5 ya que vas a registrar 6 empleados (`int empleado = 6;`) pero probablemente una de esas categorías no registres valor.

Este sería el cambio en  tu código:

```
    int categoria;
    int categoria1 = 0;
    int categoria2 = 0;
    int categoria3 = 0;
    int empleado = 6;
    int sueldo = 0;
    int promedio1 = 0;
    int sumatoria1 = 0;
    int sueldoTotal = 0;
    int sumatoria2 = 0;
    int sumatoria3 = 0;
    int promedio2 = 0;
    int promedio3 = 0;

            int sueldoCat1 = 0;
            int sueldoCat2 = 0;
            int sueldoCat3 = 0;

    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);

    for (int i = 0; i < empleado; i++) {

        System.out.println("Ingrese el numero de categoria : ");
        categoria = teclado.nextInt();
        System.out.println(i + "Ingrese sueldo : ");
        sueldo = teclado.nextInt();

        if (categoria == 1) {

            if (sueldo < 10000) {
                categoria1++;
            }
                            sueldoCat1 += sueldo;
                            sumatoria1 += 1;
        }

        if (categoria == 2) {

            if (sueldo >= 12000) {

                categoria2++;
            }
                            sueldoCat2 += sueldo;
                            sumatoria2 += 1;
        }

        if (categoria == 3) {
            if (sueldo <= 15000) {
                categoria3++;
            }
                            sueldoCat3 += sueldo;
                            sumatoria3 += 1;

        }

        if (sueldo > 15000) {

            sueldoTotal++;
        }


        /*promedio1 = sumatoria1 / 5;
        promedio2 = sumatoria2 / 5;
        promedio3 = sumatoria3 / 5;*/

    }

      if(sumatoria1>0) //Evita division entre 0              
      promedio1 = sueldoCat1 / sumatoria1;
      if(sumatoria2>0) //Evita division entre 0               
      promedio2 = sueldoCat2 / sumatoria2;
      if(sumatoria3>0) //Evita division entre 0               
      promedio3 = sueldoCat3 / sumatoria3;

    System.out.println("a)Cantidad de sueldos < 10000 en la categoria 1 : " + categoria1);
    System.out.println("b1)Cantidad de sueldos >= 12000 en la categoria 2 : " + categoria2);
    System.out.println("b2)Cantidad de sueldos <= 15000 en la categoria 3 : " + categoria3);
    System.out.println("c)Cantidad de sueldos > 15000 : " + sueldoTotal);
    System.out.println("El promedio de la categoria 1 : " + promedio1);
    System.out.println("El promedio de la categoria 2 : " + promedio2);
    System.out.println("El promedio de la categoria 3 : " + promedio3);
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias , era ese el problema ya me funciona :D , Saludos.

Comment: Me da mucho gusto, un placer ayudar @computer96 Recuerda siempre realizar tus preguntas en base a [ask] muchos Saludos!

Answer (score 1):

Yo le haria las siguientes modificaciones:

```
if (categoria == 1 && sueldo < 10000) {
 categoria1++;
 sumatoria1 += sueldo;
}

else if (categoria == 2 && sueldo >= 12000) {
 categoria2++;
 sumatoria2 += sueldo;
}
else if (categoria == 3 && sueldo <= 15000) {
 categoria3++;
 sumatoria3 += sueldo;
}

if (sueldo > 15000) {
  sueldoTotal++;
}
```

Ya que si nos damos cuenta lo que estamos sumando son los empleados que tienen ese sueldo no su sueldo.

Espero que te sea de ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

Solo tienes que cambiar los tipos de dato a números racionales en los que calculas el promedio, en este caso a double

```
int categoria;
    int categoria1 = 0;
    int categoria2 = 0;
    int categoria3 = 0;
    int empleado = 5;
    int sueldo = 0;
    int sumatoria1 = 0;
    int sueldoTotal = 0;
    int sumatoria2 = 0;
    int sumatoria3 = 0;
    double promedio1 = 0;
    double promedio2 = 0;
    double promedio3 = 0;
    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);

    for (int i = 1; i < empleado; i++) {

        System.out.println("Ingrese el numero de categoria : ");
        categoria = teclado.nextInt();
        System.out.println(i + "Ingrese sueldo : ");
        sueldo = teclado.nextInt();

        if (categoria == 1) {
            if (sueldo < 10000) {
                categoria1++;
            }
        }
        if (categoria == 2) {
            if (sueldo >= 12000) {
                categoria2++;
            }
        }
        if (categoria == 3) {
            if (sueldo <= 15000) {
                categoria3++;
            }
        }
        if (sueldo > 15000) {
            sueldoTotal++;
        }

        sumatoria1 += categoria1;
        sumatoria2 += categoria2;
        sumatoria3 += categoria3;

    }
    promedio1 = sumatoria1 / 5;
    promedio2 = sumatoria2 / 5;
    promedio3 = sumatoria3 / 5;

    System.out.println("a)Cantidad de sueldos < 10000 en la categoria 1 : " + categoria1);
    System.out.println("b1)Cantidad de sueldos >= 12000 en la categoria 2 : " + categoria2);
    System.out.println("b2)Cantidad de sueldos <= 15000 en la categoria 3 : " + categoria3);
    System.out.println("c)Cantidad de sueldos > 15000 : " + sueldoTotal);
    System.out.println("El promedio de la categoria 1 : " + promedio1);
    System.out.println("El promedio de la categoria 2 : " + promedio2);
    System.out.println("El promedio de la categoria 3 : " + promedio3);
```